# Is neovis.js version 2.1.0 incompatible with neo4j version 5.12.0?

Tags: neo4j, version, compatibility

I am using neovis.js version 2.1.0 with neo4j version 5.12.0. When I tried accessing according to the examples, the neo4j server returned the following error:

```
Neo4jError: The property existence syntax `... exists(variable.property)` is no longer supported. Please use `variable.property IS NOT NULL` instead. (line 1, column 17 (offset: 16))
"MATCH (n) WHERE exists(n.pagerank)"
```

Is there a known incompatibility between these versions?

My vue3.js code is as follows:

```
<template>
  <h3>graph demo</h3>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import NeoVis from "neovis.js";
import { onMounted } from "vue";

const config = ref({
  containerId: "graph",
  neo4j: {
    serverUrl: "bolt://localhost:7687",
    serverUser: "neo4j",
    serverPassword: "neo4j_password",
  },
  labels: {},
  relationships: {},
  initialCypher: "MATCH (n) return n",
});

nMounted(() => {
  const vis = new NeoVis(config);
  vis.render();
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`exists` has changed since Neo4j 5.0](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/5/functions/predicate/#functions-exists) to only check for graph pattern existence, not property.

neovis.js must use this variant instead:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.pagerank IS NOT NULL
```

Note: you can read the [documentation of `exists` for Neo4j 4.4](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.4/functions/predicate/#functions-exists), which indeed worked with properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

Neovis.js source code [contains this snippet](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/blob/7815563f5c118040e0d21c0f7bfd7dfbcfa5938f/src/defaults.ts#L3) in `defaults.ts`:

```
neo4j: {
    initialQuery: `MATCH (n) WHERE exists(n.pagerank)
                    WITH (n), RAND() AS random
                    ORDER BY random LIMIT 3000
                    OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
                    //WITH n,r,m WHERE exists(n.pagerank) AND exists(m.pagerank) AND exists(m.community)
                    RETURN n, r, m;`,
    ...
```

That seems to be the cause of your error. You should probably create [an issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance.

Neovis.js is compatible with Neo4j 5.12.0, with the exception of some deprecated syntax, such as `exists` mentioned above.

My error stemmed from the incorrect code `const vis = new NeoVis(config)`. It should have been `const vis = new NeoVis(config.value)`. I am using Vue3.js. Without the `.value`, Neovis.js cannot initialize the configuration and defaults to a Cypher clause containing `exists`. The error was resolved when I added `.value`, and my initial Cypher clause without `exists` will be executed.